# How to create a Filter as a component and what should I put for annotation?

Tags: filter, annotations, aem, sling

So, I am working on CQ5.  I would like to deploy a bundled component as a service to filter & modify the .inifinity.json output (from sling) to the CQ5.

I am able to build and deploy, and have both the component and bundle being active.  However, when a page or call an infinity.json , I don't see the output in log.  I suspect because the services not properly installed? or some other service return the call before running my service?  not sure.  and here is my code:

```
package com.my.test;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.*;



@Component(
        provide=Filter.class,
        immediate=true
)
public class TestFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestFilter.class);
    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public void init (FilterConfig filterConfig)  {
        LOGGER.info ("INIT .");
        this.setFilterConfig(filterConfig);
    }


    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info ("Destroy me NOW!!...");
    }


    public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain){
        try
        {
            LOGGER.info ("Within Simple Filter ... :) ");
            LOGGER.info  ("Filtering the Request ...");

          chain.doFilter (request, response);

          LOGGER.info ("Within Simple Filter ... ");
          LOGGER.info ("Filtering the Response ...");

        } catch (IOException io) {
            LOGGER.info ("IOException raised in SimpleFilter");
        } catch (ServletException se) {
            LOGGER.info  ("ServletException raised in SimpleFilter");
        }
    }

    public FilterConfig getFilterConfig() {
        return this.filterConfig;
    }

    public void setFilterConfig (FilterConfig filterConfig){
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

}
```

Am I missing anything in the annotation?  or anything that I should have done?

Answer (score 1):

Looking the discussion threads [here](http://dev.day.com/discussion-groups/content/lists/cq-google/2011-03/2011-03-03__day_communique_Servlet_Filters_Configuration_in_CQ5_4_Venkat_Vinjamuri.html) and [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sling-users/201204.mbox/%3CCAE-0ag8GgyuYX-ocuXu7+PC+BDfBGW4m4SAyk8c+ZUyc_2C0+A@mail.gmail.com%3E), it looks like you need to add annotations to set a [sling.filter.scope](http://sling.apache.org/site/filters.html) @Property, and also to declare the @Service.

Something like this:

```
@Component(
    provide=Filter.class,
    immediate=true
    )
@Service(javax.servlet.Filter.class)
@Properties({
    @Property(name = "sling.filter.scope", value = "request") 
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sling integration test services source code include a few Filters at [1], that you can use as examples. As David says, you're probably just missing the @Service annotation.

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/launchpad/test-services/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/launchpad/testservices/filters/